# Set NPM log level to "quiet" in script definition

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a simple CLI tool for my project which I run through NPM/Yarn scripts:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "cli": "dotenv ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/cli/index.ts --",
    ...
}
```

I'd like to silence the log info stuff that NPM/Yarn automatically write to stdout when a script is run.

By default, the output is:

```
$~/foo> yarn cli --help
yarn run v1.22.5
$ dotenv ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/cli/index.ts -- --help
cli <command>

Foo bar baz bat

Options:
  --help  Show help                                                    [boolean]
✨  Done in 2.42s.
```

I want to get rid of the part where it writes out the command itself, and the "Done in `x`s" part.

I know I can do it manually with `yarn --silent cli` or `npm run --quiet cli`, or I could set `loglevel=quiet` in an npmrc, but neither is preferable.

I don't want to use the npmrc as I want to retail output for other scripts, and I don't want to require users to run it with the `--silent` flag themselves.

The CLI tool generates JSON which is fed into other scripts, so it's ideal if it's clean output that can be redirected or piped without the NPM/Yarn guff.

I tried adding `--silent` to the start of the command, but that doesn't work. I tried setting `npm_config_loglevel=quiet` as an env var, but that doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can try, or is this just not supported?

Answer (score -1):

when calling [`npm run script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script) you will always get such output by default and there is no way (currently) to disable it.

if you don't want npm output, just call your script directly without using npm.

e.g. rather than executing `npm run cli`, then execute `npx dotenv ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/cli/index.ts --`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is no good for my use-case unfortunately. I need something that's as straightforward as possible, even asking users to add `--silent` as described in the question causes confusion.